# Django queryset exclude values

Tags: django, django-admin, django-queryset

models.py

```
class ChatMessage(models.Model):
    ip=models.IPAddressField()
    message=models.CharField(max_length=200)

class BlockIp(models.Model):
    ip=models.IPAddressField()
```

admin.py

```
class ChatMessageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ChatMessageAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        #block=BlockIp.objects.all()
        return qs.exclude(ip='1.1.1.1')
```

I have rewrite the queryset method for ChatMessage class.
I am trying to return something like:

```
SELECT * FROM chatmessage as v1 JOIN blockip as v2 on v1.ip!=v2.ip
```

so the user see only the messages which have an ip which is not in a blockip entry

`return qs.exclude(ip=BlockIp.objects.all().ip)` is not syntax correct :(

Any advice?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Django provides some operators that you can use when filtering values. In particular, you want the [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#in) operator. You could do something like this:

```
blocked = BlockIp.objects.all().values_list('ip', flat=True)
messages = ChatMessage.objects.exclude(ip__in=blocked)
```

`values_list` will return the given values (in this case, just the `ip` field) as a list.

Comment: ip__in that's what i am missing

Comment: i am wondering why `BlockIp.objects.all()` is enough..If the field ip in BlockIp model had a diferrent name is it anything to change in the above query?

Comment: @ChrisPappas: I haven't run the query, but yeah, you might need to tweak it a bit. Let me update.